# Why does lisp say this functon is undefined?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I write this in a source buffer:

```
 (defun make-cd (artist album rating like) 
  (list :artist artist :album album :score rating :like like))
(defvar *dab* nil)
(defun addcd (cd) (push cd *dab*))
(defun readab ()
  (dolist (cd *dab*)
    (format t "~{~10t~a--~5t~a~%~}~%" cd)))
```

I compile into the REPL by pressing C-c C-k.

The first several functions work fine from REPL:

```
CL-USER> (make-cd "dixie" "fun time" 6 "y")
 (:ARTIST "dixie" :ALBUM "fun time" :SCORE 6 :LIKE "y")
CL-USER> (addcd (make-cd "dixie" "whooola" 6 "y"))
 ((:ARTIST "dixie" :ALBUM "whooola" :SCORE 6 :LIKE "y"))
```

But the last is reported as undefined?

```
CL-USER> (readab)
  ; Evaluation aborted on #<CCL::UNDEFINED-FUNCTION-CALL #x302000B3895D>.
```

Am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: wfm in clisp - no errors, output as expected. please try the debugger.

Comment: Your original code works for me. Maybe there is something going on with packages? Try adding `(in-package :cl-user)` to the beginning of your source buffer, just to be sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the C-c C-k command not automatically saving the source before it is processed, and thus the processing is happening on the old save of the source. Save first and the problem goes away.